# Why is Task.Factory.FromAsync blocking UI thread?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a sample WinForms app with a WCF proxy. I am using the FromAsync to return a Task and waiting on the task to complete before i return the result:

```
private bool Foo() {   
  var proxy = new MyProxy();   
  var request = new ProxyRequest();

  var task = Task<ReturnType>.Factory.FromAsync<ProxyRequest>(client.BeginCall, client.EndCall, request, null);   
  task.Wait();   
  return true; 
}
```

When calling this method from a button click on the form the UI thread is blocked. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are explicitly waiting for the task to finish before continuing when calling `task.Wait()`.

Comment: @JonasStawski I suggest you post the code you're using when you've removed the `task.Wait`.  The code you've posted has an obvious flaw; the code you're working with apparently has a different one...

Comment: I will post what I'm trying to accomplish on a different question

Comment: Did you ever ask the different question?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling `task.Wait()`. It waits synchronously on the calling thread for task completion.